# a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-hosting, remote-server

I have just upload my local project(overwrite existing one that was working correctly) to remote server .

my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>

RewriteRule    ^username    http://www.google.com
#^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user/profile/USERNAME=$1
```

log error:

> SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File
>   "/home/fewextra/public_html/index.php" is writeable by group

Browser Error:
[image]

any idea how to fix ?
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442370/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) so far but no luck .

**Note: the same project when i upload to another server then it works.**

Comment: Remove everything after `[NC,L]` in last rule

Comment: Check Apache error.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fixes you tried have nothing to do with this message and is not an access issue. This is saying your permissions are too permissive. Try to make some changes and then see.

Change the permissions on your `public_html` to `755` and your `index.php` to `644`.

Comment: my public_html has already 755 rights and so is index.php 644

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

changing permissions for directories to 755 and php files and other files 
to 644

[Source](https://my.getstarted.com.au/knowledgebase/56/500-Error-File-is-writeable-by-group.html)