# Getting "You don't have permission to access / on this server" when trying to access web Application on EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf, windows-server-2012-r2

**Environment:**
Server: AWS EC2-WINDOWS 2012 R2
Web Server: Apache 2.4.17

The simple web application, is accessible from the server, using the browser with `http://localhost/` and `http://127.0.0.1/`

However, when I try to access it from outside (e.g., client, or any other machine through internet) by placing my ec2 instance public DNS ('ec2-.compute.amazonaws.com') in the browser, I get the following
[image]

Now I know this is web server issue. EC2 security rules, and Windows Server firewall have been bypassed. The issue is coming from my Apache server settings.

I spent significant time trying all possible solutions here:

[WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)
[Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server, WAMP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377476/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-wamp-error)
[Error message “Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)
[You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442370/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

I did not create virtual host though. Do I need to?

My current `httpd.conf` has the following settings:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp64/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the security group configuration. Have you enabled port 80 and 8080 for in and out port?

Comment: @JeetendraChoudhary Yes, and I think if there is issue with security groups, I should get any response from web server. The security rules come before accessing the web server.

Comment: I guess then issue is related to directory listing. can you try creating a subdirectory within / and put an index.html file there and check if you can access it?

Comment: @JeetendraChoudhary I tried. I created `root` under `www`, and added `index.html`. I tried with the url ` ....amazonaws.com/root/index.html` I got the same result `You don't have permission to access /root/index.html on this server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this has taken my whole weekend to figure out. But eventually, I found the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405288/2153567). It was like a hidden treasure among many other answers with high votes, for what seems to be a very contentious issue.

I provide an answer here that applies to the particular environment I mentioned in the questions. The changes required on the `httpd.conf` file are as follows:

1. Change `<Directory .... >` to be like this:

   `<Directory "C:/wamp64/www/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride all
       Require all granted
   </Directory>`

   where my `index.html` file is under `www` apache default directory
2. And this is where I was stuck: In the same file, search for `#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove`, below this line you'll find `Require local`. Change it to `Require all granted`.
3. Do not forget to restart Apache server.

   - Virtual host is irrelevant. Whether you are using Windows server or not. As long you have one website hosted, no need for the virtual host
   - Being hosted on EC2 is irrelevant. Since you get the `Forbidden` reply, you are bypassed EC2 security group rules, and host server firewall (in this case windows 2012 R2). The response is coming from the web server.